# $set and $save in angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

What is the difference between using $set and $save in angularfire? 
Also, is there a difference in amount of data sent to the server in the following case:

I could have a firebase object:

```
$rootScope.projectgroups= pgsync.$asObject();
```

defined at $rootScape and can save changes to it from every controller, by simply calling

```
$rootScope.projectgroups.$save();
```

I could also save changes to the server using $set and define the exact location of a childobject:

```
$firebase(pgref.child($rootScope.prgrid +
"/projects/")).$set($rootScope.prid,
$rootScope.projectgroups[$rootScope.prgrid].projects[$rootScope.prid]);
```

Is assigning new data to the childobject using $set cheaper on data transaction to the server than using $save on the entire object? Or will angularfire compare the object somehow with the object history and only push the last local changes to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between using $set and $save in angularfire?

`$set` exists as a convenience on the `$firebase` service. It can be called without having to download any data locally first.

`$save` exists on the synchronized objects/arrays. It calls `$set` internally, which can be seen by checking out the source (a great way to learn about the lib). It saves synchronized objects/arrays by converting them to JSON data and then sending them on to `$set`.

> Also, is there a difference in amount of data sent to the server in the following case

None at all

> Is assigning new data to the childobject using $set cheaper on data transaction to the server than using $save on the entire object?

It's cheaper if you don't have synchronized data locally. If you already have a collection downloaded, they are equivalent.

> Or will angularfire compare the object somehow with the object history and only push the last local changes to the server?

It does not, but Firebase handles these complexities internally so you (and AngularFire) can just code and be happy.

Comment: "which you could discover with a quick glance at the source code" Behave Kato! And don't tell them the secret sauce to most of my answers please. ;-)

Comment: Doh! Open source / secret sauce; I'm always getting them confused. :(

Comment: I've fired my behavioral therapist (curse you `M-x doctor`) and revised the offending sentence, since that was never the intent. Thanks for pointing it out.